# How to generate increasing (then decreasing) numbers with variance R

Tags: r, random-generation

I have to generate numbers which increase and decrease, with variance in them. Exactly like the following image.

[image]

I have tried rnorm but it generates random numbers which do not necessarily increase, seq which does not have variance in it.

How can i generate data as given in the image in R?

Comment: `x <- c(1:100, 100:-200, -200:150); y <- rnorm(length(x), x); plot(1:length(x), y, type = "l")`

Comment: Thank you. How can i increase the variance?

Comment: the variance is relatively constant in your image.

Comment: Ok. How can i increase jitter then? What i got from the code was lines which are relatively straight.

Comment: in the code for y, use `rnorm(length(x), x, 2)`. Increase the value of the third argument, the scale parameter until you're satisfied.

Comment: Got it. Thank you. Can you write it as an answer so that i can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use `rnorm()`:

```
set.seed(12345)
x <- c(1:100, 100:-200, -200:50)
# Draw samples setting x above as mean with appropriate constant variance 
y <- rnorm(length(x), x, 20)
plot(1:length(x), y, type = "l")
```

This should do the trick.